# Hiding button A on click of button B in Shiny

Tags: shiny, action-button

Very simple question: In my shiny UI, I have two buttons, A and B

on the click of button B I would like button A to be hidden, but I don't think updateActionButton has this capability. So how is this accomplished?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dean built wonderful `shinyjs` package that has this functionality. Note that I added `toggle` instead of `hide` but you can switch if you like

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("hide","a"),
  actionButton("b","b")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

  observeEvent(input$hide,{
    toggle("b")
  })

})
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]